# Unknow cause for mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I know that we already have thousands of this question in the site. Trust me I looked upon them.

So, my problem is that, by reasons unknow my SQL query keeps returning false, and because of that, my `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` keeps failing. But, this query was transcribed in to my phpmyadmin, and I know that works because it works there.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

require('connect.php');

$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

mysqli_select_db($conn, "cerberusdb");

$sql = "SELECT _login, _pass FROM 'tblogin' WHERE _login ='".$login."' AND _pass = '".$pass."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) > 0){

$return = 'true';
$echo $return;

}else{

$return = 'false';
echo $return;

}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

And this is the Javascript that handles the request, by the way, I know that works to, already tested the `$.post()` to know for sure if the vLogin and vPass it's been passed to the php.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

$("#logForm").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var vLogin = $("#lgInput").val(), vPass = $("#lgPass").val();

$.post('login.php', {login: vLogin, pass: vPass}, function(data, textStatus, xhr){

alert('data:'+data+'\nstatus: '+textStatus);

}); 
}); 
});
```

So, if anybody can helps I'll be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

P.s.: I've looked upon the PHP documentation and finded thar `mysqli_query()` when the query is a `SELECT` returns an object, and when fails returns false. I just can't understand why it's failing.

Comment: You're subject to sql injection. I'd suggest binding your parameters to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Single Quotes` (') are not allowed using **table name** or **column name**. Use `backtick` (`)

Change

```
'tblogin'
```

To

```
 `tblogin`
```

Like

```
$sql = "SELECT _login, _pass FROM `tblogin` WHERE _login ='".$login."' AND _pass = '".$pass."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

[**NOTE**: Click [when to use single quotes double quotes and backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) to know more

Comment: I really hates when my the problem is something ridiculous like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: No Problem @LucasLeite. *It Happens* Enjoy. *Cheers !!*

Comment: Err.. I noticed your eddition, I'm used mysqli. Didn't I?

Comment: *Oh Sorry.* I edited wrong answer of mine. No problem @LucasLeite. If you think this answer helped you. Then, please tick this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily.

Comment: just did, I have to wait for a few minutes to do that.